# Как отсортировать массив символов?

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив из символов в Java, например:

```
char[] arr = {'a', 'f', 'q', 'b'};
```

Как его отсортировать?

Comment: @ИгорьБондаренко если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его правильным (галочкой) для тех, кто в будущем посмотрим эту тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       char cArr[] = {'r','q','s','p'};
       Arrays.sort(cArr);
}
```

Comment: Я новичок. Спасибо всем, теперь знаю)

Comment: У нас не принято отправлять в поисковики и тем более lmgtfy. Ссылки оттуда ведут обратно на SO.

Comment: ссылки наглядно показывают пример правильного запроса, чтобы не было похожих вопросов по простым темам в будущем.